# Jackson-xml does not parse nested object

Tags: java, xml, jackson

Jackson does not parse xml to java object properly. It return null object although in xml this object has values. Object which is returned as null is used elsewhere and works.

I tried parse part of xml (this one which is null in java object) and it works.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties
public class Group {
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false, localName = "array")
private List<Array> array = new ArrayList<>();
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false, localName = "struct")
private List<Struct> struct = new ArrayList<>();
...
}

@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Struct {
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
private List<Par> par = new ArrayList<>();
...
}

@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties
public class Array {
@JacksonXmlProperty
private Struct struct;
...
}
```

EDIT: there is example of xml file

```
<config>
 <group name="sys">
  <desc>sss</desc>
  <define name="DYN">
   <const>1</const>
   <desc>
   </desc>
  </define>
  <par name="show_time" type="ACT" len="1">
   <snmp oid="1">ssss</snmp>
   <val>0</val>
   <desc>Show system</desc>
  </par>
  <struct name="compatibility_">
   <desc>
   </desc>
   <par name="link" type="PAR" len="1" range="0,1">
   <snmp oid="232">ssss</snmp>
   <val>0</val>
   <desc>
   </desc>
   <define name="POLL_AND_INTERRUPT">
   <mask>0</mask>
   <desc>
   </desc>
  </par>
 </struct>
 <array name="DYN_STRUCT" len="1" max="32">
  <struct name="script_" key="name">
   <desc>
   </desc>
   <par name="name" type="STRING" len="32">
   </par>
  </struct>
 </array>
</group>
```

Comment: It is hard to say what is wrong without example `XML` payload.

Comment: @MichałZiober I've added xml example above